# Total Number of Imaps and Multimaps Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there a limit on the total number of iMaps and Multimaps that can be created?

I have created around 100k small maps, the memory occupied seems high compared to a few large maps having the same data.

hazelcast verion :4.0.2

Comment: install `mancenter` and check size of maps.

Comment: mancenter doesn't show the memory consumption of a multimap, statistics are enabled. The overall size of the map is the same as the expected size

Answer (score 0):

Creating any object in Hazelcast consumes some heap memory. With the Enterprise edition of Hazelcast, the data for maps may be off-heap, but there is still the map itself on-heap. This is common to any java object.
There's no hard limit, but you may find that the memory pressure becomes excessive.
I'd like to know why you have that many maps - there may be another approach to your application. Have you looked at MultiMaps? Hazelcast supports these and this will support many key-to-collection-of-values mappings.